# SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, to-char

I am trying to have a result 'none' every time it gives me a null result. Right now it is giving me a 0 for a null result. How could I have a row show me 'none' instead of a 0 for a null result.

I have tried TO_CHAR and TO_NUMBER for the sum and I can't get it to display 'none'...

```
CASE WHEN SUM(ENROLLED) = 0 THEN 'none' ELSE SUM(ENROLLED) END AS ENROLLED
```

so when try the above I get SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

this is what I have

```
SELECT lt.STUDENT_ID,lt.FIRST_NAME, lt.LAST_NAME, CASE WHEN SUM(ENROLLED) = 0 THEN 'none' ELSE SUM(ENROLLED) END AS ENROLLED
FROM STUDENT lt
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT s.STUDENT_ID, e.ENROLL_DATE,COUNT(z.COURSE_NO)AS ENROLLED
FROM   STUDENT s
LEFT   JOIN ENROLLMENT e ON s.STUDENT_ID = e.STUDENT_ID
LEFT   JOIN SECTION z ON e.SECTION_ID = z.SECTION_ID
WHERE  s.PHONE LIKE '702%'
GROUP  BY s.STUDENT_ID, e.ENROLL_DATE) rt
ON lt.STUDENT_ID = rt.STUDENT_ID
WHERE lt.PHONE LIKE '702%'
GROUP BY lt.STUDENT_ID,lt.FIRST_NAME, lt.LAST_NAME,ENROLLMENTS;
```

instead of having

```
STUDENT_ID FIRST_NAME                LAST_NAME                 ENROLLED
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
       253 Walter                    Boremmann                     1 
       396 James E.                  Norman                        0 
etc
```

I'd like to have it like this

```
STUDENT_ID FIRST_NAME                LAST_NAME                 ENROLLED
---------- ------------------------- ------------------------- -----------
       253 Walter                    Boremmann                     1 
       396 James E.                  Norman                        none
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the function: COALESCE (cast(sum(expr1) as varchar), 'none')

As a side note, I question the use of DISTINCT in your query.

Comment: so I did COALESCE(TO_CHAR(SUM(ENROLLED)),'none') ENROLLED which gives me the sum I want , but it is not displaying 'none'...

Comment: what is it displaying?

Comment: Coalesce works with NULL not zero. That mean it alway returns SUM(ENROLLED).

Answer (score 3):

```
CASE WHEN SUM(ENROLLED) = 0 THEN 'none' ELSE SUM(ENROLLED) END AS ENROLLED
```

this returns different types. Make it the same (cast SUM to string)

Answer (score 1):

The error is normal because your command

**CASE WHEN SUM(ENROLLED) = 0 THEN 'none' ELSE SUM(ENROLLED) END AS ENROLLED**

uses the same column as string 'none' and number SUM(ENROLLED)

you can use the column as string and display the number in the same time using

CASE WHEN SUM(ENROLLED) = 0 THEN 'none' ELSE **TO_CHAR**(SUM(ENROLLED)) END AS ENROLLED

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
COALESCE(to_char(sum(expr1)), 'none')
```

This should work without using cast and varchar.